# VBScript to multiply column values in excel and paste the results in different column

Tags: excel, math, vbscript

I am trying to use a VBScript to perform the excel function below

B=A:A * 0.5

That is multiply all the value in column A by 0.5 and paste those values into column B. I would like to do this outside of Excel.

With the help of @GarysStudent 's answer, I was able to get the multiplication and pasting within the original column, Column A to work. Ideally I would like to paste the multiplied results in Column B.

Below is the VBScript code for multiplying and pasting values within the same column

```
Imports Excel = Mircosoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
 Dim objExcel, objXLWorkbook, objXLWS, RNGE, LNG, lRow, nRow
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  objXLWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\filename.xlsx")
  objXLWS = objXLWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  objExcel.Visible = True
  'Adding Helper Cell to hold the multiplication value
  objXLWS.Range("Z100") = 0.5
  With objXLWS
    LNG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row  
    RNGE = .Range("A2:A" & LNG)
    .Range("Z100").Copy()
    RNGE.PasteSpecial(Excel.XLPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply)
  End With
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Consider **PasteSpecial xlMultiply**

Comment: Please elaborate with an example @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses cell **Z100** as a "helper" cell:

```
Sub DEMO()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long
    Range("Z100").Value = 0.5
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("A1:A" & N)
    Range("Z100").Copy
    r.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
End Sub
```

Comment: I know I am missing a library to support range, as right now range autodefaults to CharacterRange. Which Library should I import in Visual Studio 2012 to support Range?

Comment: Got the range to take, however xlPasteAlll and xlMultiply are coming up as undeclared. What's the best way to declare them? Is this still a library related issue?

Comment: I am almost there, I realized I had to include Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll and Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply. The only missing piece, which I think I forgot to include in my question, was to paste the results in column B. Right now, they overwrite the original values of column A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop if you know the size of your data, or a do while if you don't:

```
Dim x As Double
x = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count
For i = 1 To x
Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value * 0.5
Next
```

This works but it is a little slow, it counts how many entries you have and then loops through. i would recommend using a spreadsheet function for speed though.